# WSO2 and Keycloak Scope Management

Tags: wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager

I aim to integrate API authentication in WSO2 with Keycloak. I've diligently followed the steps outlined in the documentation here: [WSO2 Keycloak Connector Configuration](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/).

Following these steps, I successfully generated a key and a secret for the application named "myapp." Subsequently, I subscribed this application to the PizzaShackAPI, generated a token from "myapp", and successfully called the API using the provided token.

Now, I'm looking to enhance security by generating a token with a specific scope, such as "agent." To achieve this, I created the "agent" scope in the API Publisher of WSO2 and added this scope to my PizzaShackAPI. However, I had to manually create this scope in Keycloak and assign it to the client created for "myapp" to complete the process.

My query revolves around streamlining this integration further. I want to leverage WSO2 to create and manage scopes, eliminating the need to interact directly with Keycloak. Essentially, I seek complete integration, wherein creating a scope in WSO2's API Publisher automatically results in the creation of the same scope in Keycloak. Additionally, I want to bind this scope to a specific client within WSO2.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on achieving this seamless integration between WSO2 and Keycloak.